# Gerber files can't be exported to PCB in Altium

Tags: pcb-design, altium, layout, pcb-layers, gerber

I followed [this](https://www.altium.com/documentation/knowledge-base/altium-designer/gerber-to-pcb) tutorial on how to import and generate a PCB from gerber files. At first it wasn't working because the files had the extension .pho but I fixed that. Now when I go through the steps and make it to the end and export to PCB the PCB screen shows no PCB, just the gray screen that is normally around the PCB. Has anyone got any clue what's going on? Below are the gerbers I have in case I'm missing something.

[image: gerber files]

Edit: So It turns out the PCB was in screen I just had to find it and place it within board bounds. But it looks like this and I can barely interact with it. Some guidance would be appreciated.

[image: PCB that was exported]

Comment: The Gerber files just contain the information needed to generate the photo tooling to produce the board- they do not contain any electrical or component information.  An IC footprint will just appear as a group of unrelated copper pads - you won't be able to pick up and move the footprint as a single item.  It looks like the aperture information is missing, as there are no via pads or other round pads shown.

Comment: @PeterBennett and traces are thin (zero width?), good catch. Once that's in, then you need to generate nets (check that it's reasonable, that layers are assigned and lined up correctly etc.), and then PCB export should work.

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks for your input. so is the output a PCB or something else? I was under the impression it would be a PCB. Are the above files enough? Theyre all ive got

Comment: @PeterBennett I added the aperture info thats listed in the files above, weird. Maybe its not the right one? So from what I have, would I be able to make an Assembly/ Fab drawing?

Comment: The rep file sounds like it would contain aperture data, but I don't know if it's in the right format for that ("rep" implies "report", maybe it's a text table for some reason?). I'd open it and see if it's gerber formatted, maybe it's just the RS-274D apertures. In which case it should be importable as such. Regardless, there is not enough info here to make an assembly (i.e. component centroids) drawing. Fab, should be, assuming this.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you for the replies and information, I guess this time im SOL. :'D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tim Williams answered me in the comments

> The rep file sounds like it would contain aperture data, but I don't know if >it's in the right format for that ("rep" implies "report", maybe it's a text >table for some reason?). I'd open it and see if it's gerber formatted, maybe >it's just the RS-274D apertures. In which case it should be importable as such. >Regardless, there is not enough info here to make an assembly (i.e. component >centroids) drawing. Fab, should be, assuming this